# Local path package rebuild on change

Tags: javascript, npm

I have a local package that I installed using npm [local paths](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json#local-paths) and I want my project to rebuild or re-install it every time I make some changes to that file. Does anyone know how to do it?

I tried to search online for a solution but couldn't find any.

Comment: Doesn't npm make a copy of the path in the `node_modules` after installing?

Comment: I've answered the same question here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/75800005/274312

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> TLDR; You don't have to reinstall your local package

```
npm install LOCAL_PATH
```

will create a [symlink](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symbolic_link) which means that you will be referring to your "real" library's path, as the [documentation states](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/commands/npm-install):

> `npm install <folder>`:
>
> If  sits inside the root of your project, its dependencies
> will be installed and may be hoisted to the top-level node_modules as
> they would for other types of dependencies. If  sits outside
> the root of your project, npm will not install the package
> dependencies in the directory , but it will create a symlink
> to .

for example, I have a project using a local library referred to as `something`, so when running `ls -a example/node_modules` I got:

```
drwxr-xr-x  121 fcmam5  staff   3.8K Feb 17 22:07 neo-async
lrwxr-xr-x    1 fcmam5  staff     5B Feb 17 22:09 something -> ../..
drwxr-xr-x    9 fcmam5  staff   288B Feb 17 22:07 node-oauth1
```

notice that `l` in the beginning of the second line.

So you don't have to do anything.

If you want to disable that behavior and force npm to copy the files of your local library to your node_module, [`--install-links`](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install#install-links)