# npm - Update local library dependencies automatically

Tags: javascript, npm

I have used the local package dependency feature of npm like this:

```
npm install --save "file:/path/to/module"
```

I update my library module using `npm run build` to create dist files.
Then I run `npm update` in the project using the library but it does not detect any updates.

It seems I have to update the version number to make this happen.  Is there any other way?

Comment: I recommend doing `npm update -g npm` before doing `npm update`

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Local path package rebuild on change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75510713/local-path-package-rebuild-on-change)

Comment: @Fcmam5 No tried it without `--save` with the same result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I ran into this issue. The [install](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-install) docs state that

> If <folder> sits outside the root of your project, npm will not install the package dependencies in the directory <folder>, but it will create a symlink to <folder>

In my case it wasn't creating a symlink though, it was just copying the the package over to `node_modules` - therefore not updating when a change was made.

Then I found the [link](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/commands/npm-link) command, and running:

```
npm link file:/path/to/module --save
```

Created the symlink in `node_modules`. Now updating the external package also updates the main project - because being a symlink means it's the same thing.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just to note, first you must `npm run build` your project before changes are reflected.